# How to load startup task in debug mode in PhpStorm

Tags: phpstorm, webstorm

I have a Javascript debug task in PhpStorm that I have added in the list of my Startup Tasks (Tools > Startup tasks).

Now when I open PS it opens up fine but the task is loaded in "Run.." configuration instead of "Debug.." configuration. So I can't debug it and so I always have to close it and start it again manually by clicking the "Debug" icon.

So I'm wondering if **it is possible to set Startup tasks to automatically launch the task in Debug configuration instead of Run configuration?**

Comment: As far as I'm know: you cannot; they were not made for this.

Comment: Ok, thanks. So debug button press it is for now :)